# socket io client side can't call sencha functions

Tags: node.js, sockets, extjs

I'm working on a sencha application with a grid that needs real time updates. I created a function that updates my store but can't have access to it from the client side (server side works fine)

```
socket = io.connect('http://localhost:1337');

socket.on('update', function() {
    $("#grid").update();
})
```

I tried

> document.getElementById('grid').update();

but same result:
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do that, i created an unvisible button and set the update method to the click event. On the client side:

```
    document.getElementById('refreshbtn').click();
```